# Problem with discord bot joining voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("music.py is ready!")

    @commands.command(aliases=["j"])
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if not ctx.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("...")
        else:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

- The bot "knows" when I'm in the voice channel and which one I use.
- I've tried to install and uninstall, and install again discord.py[voice]
- I've checked many times for permissions and they are there
- I've tried with roles permissions
- I didn't try with slash commands but will it work?

---

I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: what intents have you enabled?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Presence, Sever Members and Message Content intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had problem with python modules and enviorment variables. Now It's working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you elaborate on your solution, it could be helpful to people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might have forgotten to enable intents:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()  # enable privileged intents in the dev dashboard
bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Comment: I have it in my code, everything else is working. But just joining the channel - naaah.